# ObservableCollection Binding to a comboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I create  ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Tool> toolList = new ObservableCollection<Tool>();
```

And i set the DataContext in the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
    {           
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = toolList;           
    }
```

Actual:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {

       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = this;

    }
```

List to public:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Tool> ToolList
   {
       get { return toolList; }
   }
```

How I add the Objects to the list:

```
    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InputDialog input = new InputDialog();
        input.ShowDialog();
        inputNewTool = input.enteredTxt;

        if (inputNewTool != null)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Chose the Tool's directory");
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".exe";
            dlg.Filter = "Application (.exe)|*.exe";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Tool tool = new Tool();
                tool.Name = inputNewTool;
                tool.Path = dlg.FileName;
                toolList.Add(tool);
            }                
       }            
     }
```

I want that only the Name of the Toolobject is showed on the comboBox. XAML:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ToolList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
 SelectedValuePath ="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ToolList}" Height="22" 
 Name="comboBoxTools" Width="185" IsEditable="False" />
```

Edit: Now the xaml shows so:

```
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ToolList, 
   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
```

Toolclass:

```
 public class Tool
{
    public   string Name { get; set; }
    public   string Path { get; set; }

   public Tool() { }
}
```

I see nothing in the comboBox. Why? The tools are added succesfully to the Collection.
I get mad

Comment: Your `SelectedValue` is bound to the same path that is used as your `ItemsSource`. That seems fishy.

Comment: I delete Selected Value and Selected Path but this doesn't approch the problem :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set DataContext of Window to `ObservableCollection` itself.

So either *bind ItemsSource with DataContext itself* since `Binding` will automatically point to List instance.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

OR

ideally you should set DataContext to itself:

```
DataContext = this;
```

---

Moreover, `SelectedValue` is pointing to list only. That doesn't make any sense. It should point to an instance of class Tool if not using `SelectedValuePath`. And in case using SelectedValuePath, it should point to property of type string.

Either remove it completely or set it to proper instance in class.

Comment: he won't get a solution with the first proposal, because his binding for SelectedValue is wrong, too. Your second approach is correct, set `DataContext` to `this` and change the `SelectedValue` to another property (which we don't know yet).

Comment: @Herm - With first he will get items populated in comboBox. And `SelectedValue` part is for both solutions, not specific to second solution.

Comment: yes, just wanted to mention that with the first binding (with DataContext set to the list) it'll be cumbersome to bind the SelectedValue to another property of the `MainWindow`, which is definitely easier in the second solution. Of course the first one will populate the list correctly.

Comment: okay i changed data context and corrected the xaml:<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path = ToolList }" DisplayMemberPath="Name" nothing changed :(

Comment: @LittleProgrammer - Is property exist in code behind only?

Comment: yes also nothing changed with this:<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ToolList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"

Comment: hm i dont understand the question with the property in code behind

Comment: It seems valid. Can you do one thing put breakpoint on `get` of `ToolList` and see if that gets hit. Also, check output window for any binding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` in you ItemsSource-Binding

Comment: nothing changed with : <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ToolList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a simple solution on youtube(Data Binding with Windows Presenation Foundation from ht195367). I don't define the comboBox.ItemsSource in Xaml but in Window_Loaded.

```
comboBoxTools.ItemsSource = toolList;
```

For show the name of the tool I implemented ToStringng in the tool class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
        return Name;

}
```

Comment: With this approach you are moving back to traditional Winforms approach without taking any advantage of WPF binding engine. Rest definitely is your call. Have a great day..!! :)